# Files last modification date

Tags: plugins, ide, sublime-text-2

This seems like such a simple thing that I'm convinced I must be just missing it somewhere.

Is there a setting or a plugin that will display the last modification date/timestamp of the file you are working on?  Perhaps in the status bar or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I can tell this feature isn't implemented and no plugins exist for it.
You can suggest it at [Sublime Text's UserEcho forum](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/) or, if you're feeling ambitious, make a plugin that adds this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The [SideBarEnhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) package has a `statusbar_modified_time` option which displays the current file's last modification datetime in the status bar.

The datetime display format can be customised using the `statusbar_modified_time_format` setting.